# Java class variable declariation

Tags: java, selenium, scope

I'm trying to write a Selenium Java.class file to loop through multiple web browsers. However, I am hung up on a Java OOP scoping issue. The 'driver' variable below is only being allowed to be declared one time. In the first Firefox declaration. The other switch statement blocks don't like 'driver' being re-declared.

I thought I could declare 'driver' above the switch statement, however, I don't know what class to declare it as since it needs to be a different class depending upon what browser is used.

How is this kind of problem usually handled?

Thanks...

```
    switch (BrowserName){
    case "Firefox":
        FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        break;
    case "Chrome":
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
        ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        break;
    case "IE":
        System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "C:\\InternetExplorerDriver32\\IEDriverServer.exe");
        InternetExplorerDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
        break;
    case "Safari":
        SafariDriver driver = new SafariDriver();
        break;
    default:
        System.out.println("Browser not recognized.  Spawning default Firefox browser.");
        FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        break;
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're missing a very basic option, and that is to use the underlying interface that all of the various Driver(s) implement. That is [WebDriver](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html), which you could use with something like this =

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver driver = null;
switch (BrowserName){
// As before, but don't redefine driver, just assign it
 case "Firefox":
    driver = new FirefoxDriver(); // for example.
    break;
// ....
}
```

Then you should be able to use `driver` as normal.

Answer (score 1):

Do those driver classes share same super class or common interface? If so, you can do

```
BaseDriver driver = null; //before switch
```